# Manifold with special cohomology group

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am trying to find if there is a orientable compact manifold $M$ of dimension 10 with the 5th cohomology group of De Rham $H^5_{DR}(M)\cong \mathbb R$.

But, I can find such an example or prove that it is not possible. Anyone have some ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know about Poincaré duality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. There is a nondegenerate antisymmetric pairing $H^5\otimes H^5\to \mathbb R$. This means that $H^5$ can't be $1$ dimensional.

Comment: ...because in fact it must be even-dimensional. More generally if $5$ is replaced by any odd number.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Nice! But how to show it?

Comment: @Chieh: it follows by Poincare duality. On a closed orientable $4k+2$-manifold there is a nondegenerate antisymmetric pairing $H^{2k+1} \times H^{2k+1} \to H^{4k+2}$, and such things only exist on even-dimensional vector spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Got it. Thank you!